# Synthetic route for the conversion of ethanol to but-1-yne

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, alcohols

How do I convert $\ce{CH3CH2OH}$ (ethanol) to $\ce{CH3CH2C#CH}$ (but-1-yne) ?

I'm not too good with reaction mechanisms and conversions are beyond me.

**My Attempt:**

I've searched through a couple of textbooks and notes and I don't see any direct way to do the reaction.

I think I can use thionyl chloride to to convert from alcohol to chloroalkane: 
$$\ce{CH3CH2OH + SOCl2 -> CH3CH2Cl + HCl + SO_2\uparrow}$$
The $\ce{SO2}$ escapes but I'm not sure how I can get rid of the $\ce{HCl}$.

Assuming that I do get rid of it somehow, I can take the resulting chloroalkane and add an alkynyl group to it hence forming the required higher alkane.
$$\ce{CH3CH2Cl + C2HNa + NaCl -> CH3CH2C#CH + \dots}$$

Again, the mechanism of these reactions elude me. I've only figured out the above from randomly stated properties of reagents. A detailed method of the conversion would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first reaction is the conversion of the alcohol to an alkyl chloride using thionyl chloride. The [mechanism of the reaction](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/12/03/reagent-friday-thionyl-chloride-socl2/) starts with nucleophilic attack of the alcohol oxygen on sulphur, followed by displacement of $\ce{Cl-}$. Chloride then substitutes the alkyl chlorosulfite group in an $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reaction, and the latter decomposes into $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{HCl}$.

[image]

<sup>([Image source](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/12/03/reagent-friday-thionyl-chloride-socl2/))</sup>

In the second reaction, chloroethane is alkylated with sodium hydrogen acetylide to yield the desired product.

$$\ce{C2H5-Cl + HC#C^{-} ->~ C2H5-C#CH + Cl-}$$

This is a simple $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reaction, in which $\ce{Cl-}$ is substituted by $\ce{HC#C^{-}}$. [Acetylide salts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylide) of alkali metals can be prepared by deprotonation of ethyne with a strong base, for example, with butyllithium in THF or [sodium amide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_amide), which can be generated in situ by dissolving sodium metal in liquid ammonia.

[image]